# Extracting Text from the <title> Tag Using requests_html in Python

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm using Python 3.9.12 with `requests_html` to parse HTML in a local file and extract the text content of the `<title>` tag. However, when I try to extract the content, it returns more than just the text of the `<title>` tag. I need help to get just the text "Test - A Sample Website" from the `<title>` tag.

Here's the relevant part of the HTML file (named `simple.html`):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
<head>
    <title>Test - A Sample Website</title>
    <!-- Other head elements -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Body content -->
</body>
</html>
```

And here's my Python script:

```py
from requests_html import HTML

with open('simple.html') as html_file:
    source = html_file.read()
    html = HTML(html=source)

match = html.find('title')
print(match[0].html)
```

This script outputs the entire head section starting from the `<title>` tag, instead of just the text of the `<title>` tag. How can I modify this script to get only the text "Test - A Sample Website" from the `<title>` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML representation of the element, including its children, is returned by the html attribute in requests_html. Because the title tag is part of the `<head>` element, calling `match[0].html` returns the complete contents of the  element, not just the `<title>`. Instead of using `.html`, use the `.text` property to extract only the text content of the `<title>` tag. The text attribute returns the element's text content, which is what you want.

```
from requests_html import HTML

with open('simple.html') as html_file:
    source = html_file.read()
    html = HTML(html=source)

match = html.find('title', first=True)  
if match:
    print(match.text)
else:
    print("Title tag not found.")
```

Comment: Thanks for that response and information. It makes sense. However, I have just tried the above (using .text instead of .html) and it did a very similar thing - it printed out all the text within the tags starting from the title.
I have tried to run my same original code block from within my linux VM and it works as expected. So I think the problem I'm having isn't so much with python but with it's interaction with anaconda. 
Thanks again!

Comment: @Terry I ran the code personally, and if you're still getting similar output, in that case, you'll want to check your HTML file, because your title is might nested with some other element, and also try updating requests_html library.

Comment: @Terry Ah since you mentioned, try running a new anaconda environment, make sure that there are no conflicts within the packages, I am not aware of any particular issues with the requests_html package.

Comment: Thanks again. I've progressed the project I'm working on using my linux VM so I'll go ahead and close off this question as I'm not versed enough in anaconda to spend time going through that. Again, I really appreciate your help with this though. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the problem is within my anaconda environment using vscode. The python script itself works fine in my Linux environment.
So am closing this question now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).